# Are questions pertaining to investing in a specific country admissible?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

Suppose that I would like to invest in [Ruritania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania). Suppose further that I am interested in learning about the risks involved — physical, sociological, regulatory, legal, etc — and that I do **not** trust most of the material available. Would it be *admissible* to post a question on Economics SE requesting authoritative references about the risks of investing in [Ruritania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania)?

Naively, to me, this falls under [development-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development-economics). However, since I do not know what the conventions and norms on Economics SE are, I figured it would be wise to ask here on Meta before posting my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to ask about the risks of investing in a country, try narrowing the question down to be relevant to this Stack. For example, you can ask about historical inflation rates and whether there are any sources on their movement, or you could ask about how central bank policy has influenced capital assets, or some other very specific question. When I say you would want to narrow down the question, I really do mean you would need to do a good job at making it more manageable.

When you ask about the "risks" of investing in a country, this is way too broad of a topic to just ask all at once. Are you interested in a specific industry? In the labor market? In creating a small business there? In major companies that are publicly traded in that country? Start from there and try to think of a very specific activity you are interested in. You are more likely to have a viable question to ask then.

Answer (score 2):

1. Questions about personal finance (e.g. managing/investing your money) belong to the [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) stack not economics stack (this is explained in our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).
2. It is not development economics question. Development economics studies the transformation of emerging nations into more prosperous nations, the discipline has little to say about personal investment in developing countries.
3. You seem to want to ask multidisciplinary question. Such questions are often not well suited for SE format. You should consider splitting your question and asking about its separate parts in appropriate stack. For example, for legal questions you should use law stack exchange.

Comment: I asked on Money SE and it was closed.

Comment: How can one understand why a region is not more prosperous without understanding that region's sociological and legal environment?  How can one invest in a region without understanding that region's sociological and legal environment?  Obviously, I disagree with your 2nd point.  Interestingly, my question was motivated by a blog post written by a professor of economics at George Mason University on why a certain region he happened to be summering at was not more prosperous.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo 1. I don't know why it was closed there but on this site personal finance is off topic. Sometimes question does not fit any SE. 2. I never said that knowing sociological and legal factors is not relevant. However, **SE is not very good place for multidisciplinary questions**. If you have multidisciplinary question you should break it into separate disciplines and ask them separately and then do a synthesis. 3. So? A developmental economics article can motivate non-developemental articles/question. For example, does microfinance help improve welfare of poor? is developemental

Comment: economics question. If the answer is yes some people will get *motivated* to set up microfinance companies in developing countries. How to set up microfinance company is question about business administration/entrepreneurship (separate disciplines). A run of a mill professor of developmental economics will have nearly zero knowledge of business administration/entrepreneurship and vice versa. There are some people who operate on boundary of two fields and publish in multidisciplinary journals, but SE does not have multidisciplinary stacks. If you dont want to break multidisciplinary question

Comment: down, try some other economics Q&A site or some forum. Stack Exchange is not a monopoly. Different sites have different formats, some are more strict about what can be posted on some sites anything goes.